# Unhandled Exception Handled changing C++

Tags: c++, winapi

Some loaded dll changes my UnhandledExceptionHandler function. It is problem, because I use own handler for crash reporting. Is there methods to debug it?

Comment: Why don't throw `std::exception`s and use `try-catch` blocks to handle them?

Comment: "Some downloaded dll changes my UnhandledExceptionHandler function." - Why is your program loading random downloaded libraries?

Comment: sorry, in question needs to be "loaded". I've changed it

Comment: @kai: This is about SEH exceptions. C++ exceptions are built on top of SEH exceptions, but SEH is the foundation for all error reporting in Windows. Any unhandled SEH exception (including C++ exceptions implemented on top of it) eventually cause a process to terminate. Setting up an unhandled exception filter is a common way to collect diagnostic information in case of a crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

What you can do is to install a [Vectored Exception Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/vectored-exception-handling) that has more priority.

Comment: Also, if VEH is not what you want, which happens sometimes, there's a [Structured Exception Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp). Although I'd always use VEH, one have to know that there's an alternative.

Comment: Another option is to use Detours to hook the `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` function after you've called it and reject any attempts to change it in your process.